# Manipulate the document name through Connect

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to manipulate the document name when it is sent back to us using DocuSign Connect?

We have multiple envelopes with a single document in each envelope however the name of the PDF document getting sent back to us from DocuSign has the same name so it's overwriting the previously saved document.  We use the Connect method so we receive an XML file with the document pdf's and other information.  I'm trying to use the name of the document that is in the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rename the document through DocuSign Connect, however you have complete control over the document name when you are adding it to the envelope.  If you're adding through the DocuSign Console then you can just rename the file on disk before uploading.  If you're adding through the API, then you control the document name through the *name* property of the documents section of your request body:

```
    "documents": [
        {
            "name": "DocumentNameHere.pdf",
            "documentId": "1",
            "order": "1"
        }
    ]
```

When adding through the API you can programmatically set the name to whatever you want - for instance you can prompt the user of your code to enter a name, or you can append a date+time string to your filename if you're worried about file overwriting.